# Unable to open Pyspark Shell on Linux

Tags: python, linux, apache-spark, terminal, pyspark

I am running ./bin/pyspark at to open the pyspark shell but I get the following error :

```
./bin/pyspark: line 45: python: command not found env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

I have searched about it a lot. Couldn't find a solution. How should I resolve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is python installed? How does your `PATH` variable look like?

Comment: python is already installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is calling a python command, but python is not in the path. You do this by adding a link to /usr/bin.

In Ubuntu, you can try this:
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

More information found here: https://markobigdata.com/2018/01/12/installing-apache-spark-2-2-1/

Comment: You are welcome. If this solved your problem, could you please mark this question as solved, so it will help others in the future? Thank you.